# ASP.net posting a form with element name prefix "ct100$"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am writing a website master page with a form for member login
Below is the markup from the master page:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="account.aspx" method="POST">
<div class="div-topHead">
<input type="button" id="submitLogin" title="Login" value="Login" />
<input type="button" id="forgetPW" title="Forget password" value="?" onclick="window.open('forgetpassword.aspx','_self')" />
</div>
<div class="div-topTail">
<div class="div-login">
    <div class="row-body row-def">
    <input id="input_memID" name="input_memID" runat="server" type="text" maxlength="255" />
    </div>
    <div class="row-header row-def">
    Member ID:
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div-login">
    <div class="row-body row-def">
    <input id="input_memPW" name="input_memPW" runat="server" type="password" maxlength="255" />
    </div>
    <div class="row-header row-def">
    Password:
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and below is the posting script

```
$(function(){
    $('#submitLogin').click(function(){
        var f = $('#loginForm').get(0);
        $.post("../script/loginCheck.aspx", { "memID": f.inputID.value, "memPW": f.inputPW.value }, function(data){
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            if(result[0] == 1){
                //Login validated
                f.submit();
            } else {
                //Login is invalid
                alert(result[1]);
            }                    
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is, when i open the website on browser,
the text input field names are automatically added a prefix "c100$"
and then from console I can see I got below error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I have tried to lookup on the net what is this happening,
and seems it is something .NET automatically does.
Yet I could not find a way to make my post script works.

I don't need to keep the ID as it was without ct100,
as long as the posting script can work
I tried changing to f.ct100$input_memID etc but not working

Also tried the clientIDMode="Static" but can't get it work either
the browser complains clientIDMode is not an attribute of <% PAGE %>

So could someone please kindly advise what can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Blachshma's answer is perfectly reasonable and will solve your problem, I recommend simply taking off the `runat="server"` attributes on your inputs.

I can't see that you have any real reason to have these exist as [`HtmlInputText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.aspx) objects if you don't need to reference them from page code-behind.

EDIT: as per comment, if you do need to access them from code-behind, then it's a better idea to simply change the ClientIDMode to Static.

Comment: JS code invokes `f.Submit()`, so the backend needs the runat=server tag

Comment: Oh I think I understand that you mean the OP will be accessing these inputs in code behind (Page_Load for example). You're right, he should leave them in if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks Codesleuth!! Removing the runat get rid of the ct100 stuff! Appreicate :D

Answer (score 4):

**[ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)** is a property that can be added to  *individual controls*.

In addition (from MSDN):

> You can set the ClientIDMode value for all pages in a Web site by setting the pages element in the site's Web.config file. You can set the ClientIDMode value for a page in the @ Page directive.

This for instance:

```
<div id="dvDiv" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
```

Will make the div's name be "dvDiv" in both client and server side.

So `$("#dvDiv")` will work fine on the client side.

About your last remark, make sure you put it in `<%@ Page %>`  and not in `<% Page %>` (notice the `@` sign)

Comment: It can be applied in the web.config to hold globally, though. Generally desirable whenever possible.

Comment: Agree, added quote about it from MSDN

Comment: Thanks! Though i thought in jquery i needed the NAME instead of ID? ><"

Comment: No, id is fine, you just add the `#` sign before the Id name

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this jquery selector to get any element you want :-

```
$("[id$='yourElementID']")// Select an Element whose ID ends with yourElementID
```

Example :-

```
 $("[id$='submitLogin']").click(function(){
        var f = $("[id$='loginForm']").get(0);
     ....................
```

[See The Detailed Information here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/#attributevalue)

Answer (score 0):

If the Javascript code is contained inside the aspx markup, you can also use

```
var f = $('#<%= loginForm.ClientID %>').get(0);
```

Comment: no, because .js is not processed by the asp.net handler which would replace the `#<% %>` tags